# Alter the main search query to search posts by coauthor user name

Tags: wpdb, sql

I am using the Coauthors plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors-plus/

I have written some SQL in order to grab posts from authors whose display name matches the search query when searching posts.  It's actually working on a really small test blog, but it takes forever (literally so long that our host throws a 502) on a production blog.

There is only one part of this endeavor that I don't understand, which is writing an SQL query to do what I want:

- "author" is a custom taxonomy from the coauthors plugin (see link above).
- Each coauthor assigned to a post is a term from that taxonomy.
- Match the search term against the term description for coauthors.
- Get the posts that carry matching terms.

The key is that I need the results to be merged into the normal search results.  This is not a widget or a template tag or a shortcode, this needs to be the main query for the search page.  I'm achieving that via the posts_request filter (I don't have enough rep to paste a link to that filter).

Here's my SQL.  Is there anything I can do to make this more performant?

http://pastebin.com/TZA7tqCv

```
<?php

    /**
     * Create an SQL statement for searching posts by coauthor name.
     *
     * @todo I'm having trouble getting $wpdb -> prepare to work, although I don't think it's necessary since I am sanitizing the data very strictly.
     * @todo I really have no idea if this is actually how you do a JOIN.
     *
     * @param string $s The search term.
     * @param string $matching_users A comma-sep list of user ID's.
     * @param int $limit The maximum number of results.
     * @param int $offset The number of results to skip, as per pagination.
     * @return string SQL for searching posts by coauthor name.
     */
    private function sql( $s, $matching_users, $limit, $offset ) {

            // Sanitize the search term and matching users, although replacing illegal chars with a wildcard.
            $s              = $this -> sanitize( $s, '_' );
            $matching_users = $this -> sanitize( $matching_users, '_' );

            // And then hit them with esc_sql because I'm paranoid.
            $s              = esc_sql( $s );
            $matching_users = esc_sql( $matching_users );

            // Sanitize the LIMIT making sure it's an int, defaulting to 10.
            $limit = absint( $limit );
            if( empty ( $limit ) ) { $limit = 10; }

            // Sanitize the the OFFSET, making sure it's an int, defaulting to 0.
            $offset = absint( $offset );
            if( empty ( $offset ) ) { $offset = 0; }

            // We're gonna need this to build our table names.
            global $wpdb;

            // Shorten the name of the psots table for easier reading.
            $p  = $wpdb -> posts;
            $tt = $wpdb -> term_taxonomy;
            $tr = $wpdb -> term_relationships;
            $t  = $wpdb -> terms;

            $sql = <<<SQL

                    /* We're selecting posts in order to fulfill the search query. */
                    SELECT

                    /* This will prevent multiple copies of the same post, though I don't totally understand why we'd otherwise be getting them. */
                    DISTINCT

                    /* Populates a value so you can determine how many rows you would have gotten without the LIMIT clause. */
                    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

                    /* We want every column from the posts table. */
                    $p.*

                    /* I want results from the posts table, but I have to invoke these other tables for when I am sort of using them later in WHERE clause.  */
                    FROM $p, $tr, $t, $tt

                    WHERE (

                        /* See if the search term matches the post title. */
                        (
                            $p.post_title LIKE '%$s%'

                        /* See if the search term matches the post content. */
                        ) OR (
                            $p.post_content LIKE '%$s%'

                        /* See if the post author is in the array of author ID's that I have from my script. */
                        ) OR (
                            $p.post_author IN ( $matching_users )

                        /* This is the part where I'm hazy. */
                        ) OR (

                            /* Search the TT table for terms from the 'author' taxonomy ...  */
                            (
                                $tt.taxonomy = 'author'

                            /* ... and whose term description matches the search term ...  */
                            ) AND (
                                $tt.description LIKE '%$s%'

                            /* ... and whose ID matches the ID in the terms table where ...  */
                            ) AND (
                                $tt.term_id = $t.term_id

                            /* ... the term_id matches the TR table where ...  */
                            ) AND (
                                $tr.term_taxonomy_id = $t.term_id

                            /* ... the object_id in the TR table matches the post ID ... */
                            ) AND (
                                $tr.object_id = $p.ID
                            )

                        /* End the part where I'm hazy. */
                        )

                    /* Limit results to the normal post types. */
                    ) AND $p.post_type IN (
                        'post', 'page'

                    /* Limit results to the normal post status. */
                    ) AND (
                        $p.post_status = 'publish'

                    /* WP Core does this and I have no idea why. */
                    ) AND (
                            1 = 1
                    )

                    /* Get results in reverse cron, like usual. */
                    ORDER BY $p.post_date DESC

                    /* Of course we only want our normal posts per page. */
                    LIMIT $limit

                    /* And we need to account for pagination. */
                    OFFSET $offset

SQL;

            return $sql;
    }
```

Comment: Please add your code to your question in an [edit]. Do not use third party services to host your code. Thank you :-)

Comment: Oh, my apologies.  Did not realize that.  Seems like a big block to read in this format, but if you say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out by realizing that I could build a list of coauthor id's using the template tags that ship with the coauthors plugin.  Next, I observed how WordPress core does joins to query by taxonomy, but var_dumping the posts_request on a term archive page.  At that point, I just had to swap in my coauthor ID's and it works great.